# Where we get dataset for doing ML project?

Tags: dataset

Where do I get dataset for ML project and my topic is side effects of a particular drug based on age and gender with 400k datas?

Comment: Please check this - [how to ask question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of datasets online. I like [data.world](https://data.world/) because of the tools and community it provides. Whatever set you use, make sure the data is ethically sourced and diverse.

Comment: I didn't get exact dataset but anyway thanks .If any other suggestions please mention.